# Reload function only works once (Python)

Tags: python, import, reload, importerror, spyder

I am working with some code in which I have to access functions that are stored in a directory other than the rest of python's modules (my script is in `C:/path/M461/DataMapping`, the module is in `C:/path/M461/ModuleDir` and is named `functions.py` - original, I know). My prof said that using `importlib.reload` was necessary to use the functions, but I'm having a technical error with `reload`. Here is my code:

```
parentDir = r'C:/path/M461/'
if parentDir not in set(sys.path):
    sys.path.append(parentDir)
from ModuleDir import functions
dir(functions)

import importlib
importlib.reload(functions)

fieldDict = functions.fieldDictBuild()
```

When I run it, the very first time it works perfectly. Any subsequent attempts to run the file throw the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Kristen\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 147, in reload
raise ImportError(msg.format(name), name=name)

ImportError: module ModuleDir.functions not in sys.modules
```

The only workaround I have found is to completely restart the kernel every time I run the code, which is getting annoying. Is there a way to fix this permanently? Is it a problem with my code or with the `reload` module itself? And why is it necessary to reload `functions` at all?

Comment: Your import already worked; unless you changed the source code of that function or deleted globals from it, there should be no need to reload anything.

Comment: ...What is "the kernel"? Your question doesn't make any sense. Please describe exactly what you are doing, how you are launching/executing that code.